# Creating a report with GA4 data API and using segments

Tags: google-analytics-api, gdata-api, google-analytics-4

I understand that GA4 data API does not support segments yet. I read that you can imitate a segment using audiences. In my code, I create a new dimension 'audienceName', however, it only returns 'All users' audience. How can I select the audience I manually created in GA4 UI with the criterias needed for my query to show me the data I want ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I'm stuck on same issue